# Why does Firebase's Realtime Database's child_removed event handler not execute?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database contains:

```
user: {
  'monkey': 'banana',
  'bear': 'fish'
}
```

Why does the event handler not execute?

```
let db = firebase.database();

let user = db.ref('user');

user.on('child_removed', (e) => {
  console.log(e.val());
});

user.child('monkey').remove();
```

Comment: I'm not really clear on what the confusion is here.  What are you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've made the question much simpler for the moment being. Would be grateful if you had a look

Comment: @tonitone120 what are expecting here? Do you want to remove the child and then watch it through a listener?

Comment: @AmaarshallYaswankar Yes.

Comment: How are you concluding that it is not working? Also are you removing an element using `remove()` or manually removing it from the firebase console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some race going on with the code, because I tested and if you do something like this:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
    user.child('monkey').remove();
  },2000);
```

it seems to work. Here is a fiddle I used to test it out, hope it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/bgthp4wc/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think in your fiddle you are manually creating the db with `.set`. my code is not doing that and I don't expect to have to do that in order to register a deletion.

Comment: I already had a db created. I created another fiddle with a button to remove the `monkey: banana` value and show the response on the html with the child_removed callback

Comment: nothing's happening when I click 'remove' button. In any case, if the solution was that the event won't fire on initial execution of the script - but it will when removing the data is delayed...this doesn't work for me. The `'child_removed'` event isn't being triggered

Comment: are you removing the value with the firebase console?

Comment: Are you talking about your fiddle or my code? If your fiddle: I'm clicking the remove button. In my code, I'm removing with the `'remove()'` method as shown in the code in my question

Comment: and you are sure you have a child property inside `user` named `monkey` because if you don't it won't be called either.

Comment: Did you really get it to work? For the life of me I cannot understand why this simple event is not firing. I'm deleting a direct value of user.

Comment: Yes. Could you plug your firebase credentials here http://jsfiddle.net/vy02at35/ , then press `Add Monkey` then `Remove Monkey` and check the console for any errors?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the problem: https://jsbin.com/hujalop/edit?js,console. Toggle the the `if` to switch between creating the data, and reproducing the problem. It's indeed a race condition, as putting a the `remove` in a timeout indeed fixes it. But the timeout has to be pretty long, which makes it seem like it's performing the remove before the listener is attached. I added a `value` listener too, because that will always fire (and makes no difference to the network traffic) and you can see that without the delay the client never gets the `monkey` key, so it doesn't know it was removed

Comment: @WilsonPena I got it to work with your fiddle and have got it to work in my code now. Thanks for your help